# Gatling : I am getting "Invalid redirect to the same request" error

Tags: scala, testing, load, gatling

I am using below code.

```
def PostLoginRequest() = {
    exec(
      http("Login request")
        .post("${loginLocation}")
        .formParamMap(Map("UserName" -> "${username}", "Password" -> "${password}", "AuthMethod" -> "FormsAuthentication"))
        .check(xpath("//input[@name='wa']/@value").saveAs("waR"))
        .check(xpath("//input[@name='wresult']/@value").saveAs("wresultR"))
        .check(xpath("//input[@name='wctx']/@value").saveAs("wctxR"))
    )
}

def PostHomePage() = {
    exec(
      http("post Home page")
        .post("web/")
        .formParamMap(Map("wa" -> "${waR}", "wresult" -> "${wresultR}", "wctx" -> "${wctxR}"))
    )
}
 
def GetHomePage() = {
    exec(
      http("Get Home page")
        .get("web/")
        .check(regex("""var requestToken = \'(.*)\';""").find.saveAs("requestToken"))
    )
}
```

But I am getting below error for PostHomepage function on gatling

> Invalid redirect to the same request.

Comment: In case you're using an old version, you should upgrade (latest is 3.6.1 as of now) to make sure you're not facing a long time fixed bug.

Comment: If issue is still present in 3.6.1, please provide the full TRACE logs (see logback.xml file)